# Custom "Request" class is not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to explore built-in form validation in Laravel 5 as it is described here :

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-form-requests#2.-create-your-controller

But I always get an error saying that "MyRequest" class is not found.

```
// My route
Route::post('/contacts', ['as' => 'contacts-store', 'uses' => 'ContactsController@store']);

// My custom request
namespace Demo\Http\Requests;
use Demo\Http\Requests\Request;

class ContactsRequest extends Request {} // now Laravel cannot find this class

// My controller
namespace Demo\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Demo\Http\Requests; // namespace where I put my request to
use Demo\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Demo\Http\Requests\ContactsRequest; // direct reference to the class

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(ContactsRequest $request)  // this line throws exception
    {
    }
}
```

**Question :** I added all needed namespaces at the top of my controller but Laravel still cannot find my ContactsRequest class, how is that possible?

**Update :** I have just remembered that I changed global name of my application with `php artisan app:name Demo`, after this some files get lost, so I executed `php composer dump-autoload` and ContactsController found my ContactsRequest, but now I have another exeption saying that parent class `Request` is not found ...

Comment: Have you declared namespace in ContactsRequest correctly? Putting a class in a folder is not enough, maybe "namespace Demo\Http\Requests;" is missing at the top of the file?

Comment: @jerdzej.kurylo : yes, I have needed namespace at the top `namespace Demo\Http\Requests`, in addition, I generated this request class with `php artisan make:request ContactsRequest` so I believe it should not contain errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. When I was not able to find ContactsRequest class because I renamed my application from `App` to `Demo` and it seems to be common problem described here :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-class-appconsolekernel-not-found

When I did `php composer dump-autoload`, Laravel cleared some cache and `ContactsRequest` class was found.

But there appeared another exception saying that now `Request` class does not exist. This time it was my fault because I really moved it to another place.

**Conclusion :**

- when you run `php artisan app:name NewAppName` make sure to run `php composer dump-autoload` each time when you generate new class
- second error was my mistake so I needed to check that parent class has correct namespace
- do not use `php artisan app:name NewAppName` unless you really need it, as it brings unpredictable behavior of autoload

Comment: Thanks much! I was pretty much lost with this one.

Answer (score 15):

For those of you still having issues even after following the above answers I found another potential reason this error might occur. The error is mis-leading, for me there was a parse error: syntax error in my Request (missing comma in the rules array). So double check your file for errors!!

I discovered it after calling pulling my hair out and writing: `new MyCustomRequest()` within my `store()` method of my controller.

Comment: Yup... it's mis-leading. Resolved after rechecking and fixing syntax error in rules array. Thanks Dude!!

Comment: Can confirm! Using Laravel 5.6; this error was thrown because I misused the wrong Validator path: Using `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` instead of `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` when overriding `protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)` caused this exception.

Comment: a comma was missing, but the error should be something explaining the issue, very strange

Answer (score 5):

If you have generated request properly by following command

```
php artisan make:request ContactsRequest
```

Double check that you have a file named ContactsRequest.php under

```
app/Http/Requests
```

Folder. If you have one under that folder you will be able to use your custom ContactsRequest in following way:

```
public function somefunction(Requests\ContactsRequest $request)
```

Also in your ContactsRequest file you should set the array value to true instead of false. I forgot the name of that function and cannot verify as I am writing this answer from my phone.

Comment: I have just updated my question, I was able to resolv issue with missing ContactsRequest class but now Laravel cannot find default Request class, any suggestions?

Comment: Request is not found in your custom request class or in your controller ?

Comment: it is not found in custom ContactsRequest class

Comment: resolved it, second issue appeared to be my mistake with wrong namespace

Comment: Good to hear that you sorted it